# How can I delete rows from a table in a REST API, using html, javascript and java springboot?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot

I would like to delete the "users" by their IDs but I don't know how I connect the ajaxfunctions part with my Rest API backend in SpringBoot.

[Here you can see my already created table.  Löschen is meaning deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cv0d.png)

This is my delete Method in my Service class:

```
    public void deleteSportler(long id) {
    sportlerRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

And this the part of the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/sportler/{id}")
public void deleteSportler(@PathVariable long id) {
    sportlerService.deleteSportler(id);
}
```

I tried this in the ajaxfunctions part, but I don´t know if this is the right way at all

```
function deleteSportler(id){
 
$.ajax({
             url: '/sportler'+id,
             method: 'DELETE',
             data: JSON.stringify(sportlerId), .
             contentType:'application/json',  
             success: function () {
                 alert('record has been deleted');
                 loadDataTable()
             },
             error: function (error) {
                 alert(error);
             }
         })
```

I really don´t know if I am on the right way, I would really appreciate if someone can help me out with a solution.

Comment: there is a `/` (`"/sportler"+id` will give `/sportler1/` if id is 1, change it to `"/sportler/"+id`) missing at your url, furthermore, you have a relative path here meaning that it will only work if the pages are served by this `spring-boot` server.

Comment: Its for my project in the university, so its fine that this will only work on my localhost. The missing slash is a good point you have mentioned, this would have caused problems for sure. Thank you

Comment: have you tested your code before asking your question ? Even if there are no apparent reason for it not to work, when programming you don't know what errors can come into play so run it until it works